# PHP displays tags in different order

Tags: php, html-table

I have following problem, I have list of products in a database and want to display them in table unfortunately it plays some tricks for me because it displays one td before table even begins.

Here are the PHP functions:

```
<?php
function displayProduct($code,$url)
{
    echo '<form method="post" action="cart_update.php"><input type="hidden" name="code" value="' . $code . '"/>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="' . $url . '" />';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" /><input type="submit" value="Add" /></form>';
}

function displayItem($obj,$url)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $obj->menuposition . '</td><td>' . $obj->name . '</td><td>' . '£'.$obj->price . '</td><td>' . displayProduct($obj->code,$url) .'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    if(strlen($obj->description) > 2)
    {
        echo '<tr><td colspan="4" style="font-size: 10px;">' . $obj->description . '</td></tr>';
    }

}
?>
```

And here is the HTML output that I get:

[image]

Could someone help me ?

Comment: `it displays one td before table even begins` <- I am not seeing this in your screenshot. There is no TD before the table begins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `echo` call from `displayProduct` happens before the `echo` call of `displayItem` occurs.

I can see two solutions.

1: `displayProduct` should *return* the things to write and not `echo` them.

2:

```
 echo '<td>' . $obj->menuposition . '</td><td>' . $obj->name . '</td><td>' . '£'.$obj->price . '</td><td>';
 displayProduct($obj->code,$url);
 echo '</td>';
```

Answer (score 1):

displayProduct($code,$url) should return the string instead of printing it out:

```
function displayProduct($code,$url)
{
    $result = '<form method="post" action="cart_update.php"><input type="hidden" name="code"             value="' . $code . '"/>';
    $result .='<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="' . $url . '" />';
    $result .='<input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" /><input type="submit" value="Add"     /></form>';
    return $result
}
```

Comment: Yay beat you by 6 seconds.

Comment: And I would recommend my second solution, because this would be `formatProduct` and not `displayProduct` as it would not display anything any more.

Answer (score 1):

[Edit] I should read better the questions...

But this still applies:

Also as Adrian stated, you should not `echo` the lines in "displayProducts", but return a string.

Comment: Alls inputs have `/>`, xhtml is different from html.

Comment: You're right, I thought it was the form tag which was closing, it's actually the input tag. Sorry !